# How to store bash array | sed to variable

Tags: bash

How do I store this in a variable? I have the following:

```
for index in ${!array[*]}
  do
    echo ${array[$index]} | sed -e 's/.*\(pattern\).*/\1/g'
    myvar=$(${array[$index]} | sed -e 's/.*\(pattern\).*/\1/g')
  done
```

> > pattern
> >
> > error

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You can directly loop with elements instead of looking from the index.  Also, since the assignment is in the loop, the last value will overwrite the previous assignments.  Is this what you want?

Comment: I have 2 arrays of equal lengths and don't feel like dealing with tuples for this code. So I'll just loop through both at once using the same index number. And yes, I want the values to be overwritten since they will be thrown into a function. This function will need to process each index of the array the same.

Comment: BTW, why the use of `sed` here? Typically, this kind of expression can be done much more efficiently with a parameter expansion; see BashFAQ #100: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Comment: Also, what's the "this" you mean to store in a variable? If you mean the code itself, that's what functions are for; see BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $() syntax is similar to the `` syntax. The contents are treated as a command line to execute and then represent the results. So when you do

```
myvar=$(${array[$index]} | sed -e 's/.*\(pattern\).*/\1/g')
```

it's trying to run the command with the same name as the value of $array[$index] -- then pipe the result of that command to sed.

Try:

```
myvar=$(echo ${array[$index]} | sed -e 's/.*\(pattern\).*/\1/g')
```

Comment: Needs more quoting. Look at what happens if `${array[$index]}` is a glob expression (ie. `*`).

Comment: Separate issue from the original question though.

Comment: Sure, but going down that route leads to the ABS -- a resource that teaches N different good practices accurately, but shows code that would be buggy if applied literally in half its examples (which, in practice, people **do** apply literally -- because to do otherwise they'd need to cross-reference every technique seen in every example to know if that code is sound). Helping people unlearn bad habits they picked up from the ABS is one of the more unpleasant pasttimes of freenode's #bash channel.